# How to query multiple STRUCTs in BigQuery in wildcard-like way

Tags: google-bigquery

I struggle to query multiple STRUCTs which share same record fields each other.
Let me show you how the table looks like.

[Tables with multiple STRUCTs with same record fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqqtF.png)

Each `mango`, `melon`, `apple`, `banana` STRUCT(RECORD) share same fields-`qty`, `price`.

Now I want to query them at once like "Show me the `qty` > 5."
Is ther any wildcard-like way to do this? Maybe something like `SELECT %.qty >5`. Of course It is an invalid way(just for an example).

I know that the best way is to change the schema like `fruit`, `fruit.qty`, `fruit.price` and put the `mango` and others to `fruit` filed data, not remain them as a field itself.

However for some reason, I want to keep that schema and query multiple RECORDs at once. Could It be possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
with temp as (
  select 
    trim(fruit, '"') as fruit, 
    cast(json_extract(info, '$.qty') as int64) as qty,
    cast(json_extract(info, '$.price') as float64) as price
  from your_table t, 
  unnest(split(trim(to_json_string(t), '{}'), '},')) record,
  unnest([struct(
    split(record, ':{')[offset(0)] as fruit, 
   '{' || split(record, ':{')[offset(1)] || '}' as info)
  ])
)
select * 
from temp
where qty > 5
```

if applied to sample data like in your question - output is

[image]